Error while performing an Http Post operation with curl
I am issuing a post request which will post a file using curl commmand from my bash automated test file (.bats) , however the request fails with an error .
The followign is the request
@test "Test 1" {

    sleep 5s
    
 
    TEST_URL_HTTP="http://10.15.33.230:8080/service/v1/lb"
    RESPONSE=""
    for x in {0..20} ;
    do
        echo "Sending request to $TEST_URL_HTTP"

        RESPONSE=$(curl --connect-timeout 1 -s -f -X POST  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '@./folder/request.json' $TEST_URL_HTTP) && break
        sleep 5
    done
    
    if [ $x -lt 20 ] ;
    then
        echo "Received echo response"
    else
        echo "Failed to get echo response"
        exit 1
    fi
    
}

result
[INFO]      [exec] # Sending request to http://10.15.33.230:8080/service-a/v1/lb
[INFO]      [exec] # $ RESPONSE=$(curl --connect-timeout 1 -s -f -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '@request.json' $TEST_URL_HTTP)
[INFO]      [exec] # $ curl --connect-timeout 1 -s -f -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '@./folder/request.json' $TEST_URL_HTTP
[INFO]      [exec] # curl: option -d: error encountered when reading a file

appreciate any help
thank you

the error says it cant read ./folder/request.json

I ran the same command from the terminal and it worked . the file is present in the folder

Are you running the test script from the same directory? The path to the file is relative, so the value of $PWD (current directory) matters. It's not relative to where the script lives.

yes that was the issue. thank you

my bats scripts were called from a parent shell script , fixed the issue by changing the location of json file
